# How to create domodal dialog box in mfc dynamically?

Tags: mfc

i have created two dailog box statically.

```
CParentDailog
CMyDailog
```

and then

```
CParentDailog
{
CMyDailog *l_pdailog;
}
```

in oninitdailog of CParentDailog ia mdoing

```
l_pdailog = new CMyDailog();
l_pdailog ->create(ID_DAILG1); // this is id of CMyDailog
l_pdailog ->Domodal(); // crashing at this point
```

why it is crashing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you need to set parent window:

```
l_pdailog = new CMyDailog(pWndparent);
l_pdailog ->Domodal();
```